# salesforce Files User permission for SOQL

Tags: soql, python

I am trying to use Phyton/Beatbox and execute a query

```
SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkEntityId = 'Case ID goes here'
```

The purpose is to list the files attached to customer cases via UI (not as attachments).

Even though I could see customer case has files uploaded via UI, the query returns NULL. Do I need super user or more privilege than support user?